# CURL by commands

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make a PUT list by command but I get the following error.

Code:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/lecordonbleu/documentos/_update_by_query -d '{'script':   'ctx._source.codigoTema =  '1' ; ctx._source.tema = 'ACEITES Y GRASAS'  ', 'query': {'term' : {'codigoTema' : '66'} } }';
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/lecordonbleu/documentos/_update_by_query -d '{'script':   'ctx._source.codigoTema =  '2' ; ctx._source.tema = 'ADITIVOS ALIMENTARIOS'  ', 'query': {'term' : {'codigoTema' : '67'} } }';
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/lecordonbleu/documentos/_update_by_query -d '{'script':   'ctx._source.codigoTema =  '3' ; ctx._source.tema = 'ADMINISTRACION'  ', 'query': {'term' : {'codigoTema' : '68'} } }';
```

Error:
[Error executing script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UfEw.png)

It should be noted that when I run it in Sense I do not get any errors, updating correctly.
Could you help me or tell me what I'm failing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to use double quotes in your JSON, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: where should the quotation marks go?

Comment: `'{"script":   "ctx._...}'` The single quotes are only useful to wrap the whole query

Comment: I get the following error

Comment: {"error":"ElasticsearchException[Couldn't parse query from source.]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('1' (code 49)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at [Source: [B@35f4d2b2; line: 1, column: 43]]; "}

Comment: My code POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/lecordonbleu/documentos/_update_by_query -d '{"script":   "ctx._source.codigoTema =  "1" ; ctx._source.tema = "ACEITES Y GRASAS"  ", "query": {"term" : {"codigoTema" : "66"} } }';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script also needs to go into the `"inline"` parameter. You need to do it like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/lecordonbleu/documentos/_update_by_query -d '{"script": { "inline":  "ctx._source.codigoTema =  ''1'' ; ctx._source.tema = ''ACEITES Y GRASAS''"}, "query": {"term" : {"codigoTema" : "66"} } }';
```

Since you're running ES 1.6, you need to do it like this:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:9200/lecordonbleu/documentos/_update_by_query -d '{"script": "ctx._source.codigoTema =  ''1'' ; ctx._source.tema = ''ACEITES Y GRASAS''", "query": {"term" : {"codigoTema" : "66"} } }';
```

And make sure you have installed the proper version of the ["update by query" plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery)

Comment: I get the following error : "error":"ElasticsearchException[Couldn't parse query from source.]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: [B@47181414; line: 1, column: 163]]; "},"1":...

Comment: {"error":"ElasticsearchException[Couldn't parse query from source.]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: [B@47181414; line: 1, column: 163]]; "}

Comment: {"error":"ElasticsearchException[Query is required]"},"1":{"error":"ElasticsearchException[Query is required]"},"2":{"error":"ElasticsearchException[Query is required]"},"3":{"error":"ElasticsearchException[Query is required]"},"4":{"error":"ElasticsearchException[Query is required]"}}}]}

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: I'm using the 1.6

Comment: Thank you very much. It came out perfect.

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out !